# Push Data to DetailView Controller from plist

Tags: ios, objective-c

I had read many of post still cannot push data to my DetailViewController from my plist

I tried run on simulator, show CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null)

This is complete on my CustomTableViewController.m

```
#import "CustomTableViewController.h"
#import "customCell.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface CustomTableViewController ()<UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>


@property (nonatomic, strong)NSArray *contactsArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSDictionary *contact;


@end

@implementation CustomTableViewController

@synthesize contactsArray, contact;



- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self){
    //Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"contacts" ofType:@"plist"];

contactsArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [contactsArray count];
 }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath        *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
customCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier       forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...

contact = contactsArray[indexPath.row];

NSString *firstName = contact[@"firstName"];
NSString *lastName = contact[@"lastName"];
NSString *imageName = contact[@"imageName"];
NSString *cost = contact[@"cost"];
NSString *property = contact[@"property"];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

customCell.customFirstNameLabel.text = firstName;
customCell.customLastNameLabel.text = lastName;
customCell.customImageView.image = image;
customCell.customcostLabel.text = cost;
customCell.custompropertyLabel.text = property;

return customCell;
}


-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cellforRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Card Background.png"]];
}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}
```

hope someone can help!!!!Many Thanks

This is apart of my plist

```
     <dict>
    <key>firstName</key>
    <string>【騎士】聖夜型トール</string>
    <key>lastName</key>
    <string>傭兵</string>
    <key>imageName</key>
    <string>【騎士】聖夜型トール.png</string>
    <key>property</key>
    <string>闇</string>
    <key>rare</key>
    <string>UR</string>
    <key>cost</key>
    <string>5</string>
    <key>skillName</key>
    <string>制裁剣=討伐絆人（ホーリーデストロイ）</string>
    <key>normalSkill</key>
    <string>敵単体物理6,541闇ダメージ</string>
    <key>awrokenSkill</key>
    <string>敵単体物理10,851闇ダメージ、チェイン数で威力アップ</string>
    <key>hp</key>
    <string>1385</string>
    <key>pa</key>
    <string>231</string>
    <key>ma</key>
    <string>0</string>
    <key>heal</key>
    <string>0</string>
    </dict>
```

And I need to push that all to DetailViewController due to I selected row in my CustomeTableViewController, now is nothing appear

And I my DetailViewController.h

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController{
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *firstName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *property;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *rare;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cost;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *hp;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *pa;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *heal;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ma;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *skillName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *normalSkill;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *awrokenSkill;


@property int selectedRow;

@end
```

Then DetailViewController.m, i had done this

```
@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize imageName;
@synthesize firstName;
@synthesize lastName;
@synthesize property;
@synthesize rare;
@synthesize cost;
@synthesize hp;
@synthesize pa;
@synthesize heal;
@synthesize ma;
@synthesize skillName;
@synthesize normalSkill;
@synthesize awrokenSkill;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
[scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 800)];

NSDictionary *picturesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle     mainBundle] pathForResource:@"contacts" ofType:@"plist"]];
NSArray *imageArray = [picturesDictionary objectForKey:@"imageName"];
imageName.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:self.selectedRow]];



}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

Thanks again on any help!!!

Comment: Provide the code for: `objectInListAtIndex` that you call in your `prepareForSegue`. Also your issue is unclear, have you printed `selectedRow` inside `DetailViewController`, are you getting any value or nil??? also what is its data type?

Comment: what the hell? dude, never post something like this in a comment, edit your question and use code formatting so its readable. Further more this doesn't answer my comment. What is your issue, you have a plist and want to send that to another vc. What is not working, can you not get the object out of the plist, can you not read it on the other side etc. Please read my first comment again and post the code / answers I asked for

Comment: sorry sir I edit again

Comment: What does `objectInListAtIndex:` return?  The name suggests an object of some kind but you're assigning it to an `int`.  (`@property int selectedRow;`)

Comment: @PhillipMills thanks for reply , this is my first app so i am not really know how to work for , objectInlistAtIndex: that I had read other post here try to fix my issue, i not really know how and why, i just learn from here and i now finish a tableview data from plist but i can't push any view or text to a detailview while i selected a row, please

Comment: Rule #1: Don't use code if you don't understand what it does.  (Also, it's hard to help if you don't describe the problem in detail.  You say "can't push..." but you don't say if that's because you have a compile error, a run-time error, or just don't see the data that you expect to see.)

Comment: @PhillipMills thanks for teaching me!! I had deleted some code I didn't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the thing you want to pass is `contactsArray[indexPath.row]`, which is a `NSDictionary`.  (I say this because I'm assuming that `NSString *firstName = contact[@"firstName"];` works correctly.)

To do that you need a `NSDictionary` property in your detail view controller instead of `selectedRow`.  Something like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *picturesDictionary;
```

Then you would create a `prepareForSegue:` method similar to what you had except that you would pass  the `contactsArray[indexPath.row]` dictionary to the destination controller.

In the detail view controller's `viewDidLoad`, you should then be able to get the path to the image by using...

```
NSString *imgName = picturesDictionary[@"imageName"];
```

...instead of re-loading the plist that you already loaded in your first controller.

(I suggest using `NSLog` statements frequently so that, if things don't happen as you expect, you'll see the contents of the data you're passing around.)

Comment: thanks for your kindly handling, now i understand how's work^^